# Is it possible to authorize a user in GitLab using SAML

Tags: gitlab, keycloak, saml, gitlab-ce

I am wondering if it is a way to automatically assign a role to a user for a specific group in GitLab when using SAML?

We are using Keycloak as our IdP together with the community edition of GitLab. We have been able to configure GitLab so that we can authenticate the user through Keycloak. Although we want to automatically assign the user to GitLab groups and roles, based on roles in Keycloak. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is only available in Enterprise Edition of Gitlab. For community edition you can only specify if the user is external (Freelancer) or not.